# PyPDF2でseek of closed fileのエラーを解消したい

Tags: python

pythonのPyPDF2についてです。以下のコードで`ValueError: seek of closed file`のエラーが出ます。その原因を教えて頂きたいです。
mac OS
python 3.8.18
PyPDF2 3.0.1
を使用しています。

```
def main():
  import sys
  import os
  import PyPDF2

  # PDFの読み込み
  pdf_path = 'sample/sample.pdf'
  with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as rf:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(rf, strict=False)
    page = reader.pages[1]

  # PDFの書き込み
  writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
  writer.add_page(page)
  output_path = 'hoge.pdf'
  with open(output_path, 'wb') as wf:
      writer.write(wf)

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
  main()
```

Comment: 参考: [How to append PDF pages using PyPDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795091/2322778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writer.add_page`する前に`rf`を閉じているのが原因です。
閉じる前に書き込んでください。

```
def main():
  import sys
  import os
  import PyPDF2

  # PDFの読み込み
  pdf_path = 'sample/sample.pdf'
  with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as rf:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(rf, strict=False)
    page = reader.pages[1]
    # PDFの書き込み
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    writer.add_page(page)  # rfを閉じる前に書き込むこと
    output_path = 'hoge.pdf'
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as wf:
        writer.write(wf)

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
  main()
```